# Are new iOS7 icons from Session 208 available for use?

Tags: ios, ios7, icons

In the WWDC 2013 video "Session 208 - What's New in iOS User Interface Design", at 38:00, it shows many new icons added to iOS7.  There were new icons for tab bars, toolbars, settings, etc shown at that time in the video.

Are these just for Apple apps, or are they available for us to use?  And if so, where are they, or how do we put them to use?  They only mentioned their existence in the video, but did not say either way about our use.